# android timer work in anyway

Tags: java, android, time

I want to make an timer for 10 min . but the problem is that I don't want to user could handle the system time or shutdown the  device for cheating . 
is there any way to work this timer even user change the device time or shutdown the device ?
thank you for any help .

Comment: You mean keep track of the countdown when the device is off? I don't think that's possible, but you could store the time at shutdown and then resume where it left off on power up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`ACTION_TIME_CHANGED` Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_CHANGED) broadcast you can detect when the device time is changed.

You need to add the broadcast intent to your Manifest to trigger your receiver when this type of intent is detected.

```
<receiver android:name=".TimeChangedReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

To handle the Broadcast use a [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html):

```
public class TimeChangedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Logic here
        //If you have multiple broadcast registered take action for each
    }

}
```

The phone adjusts the time periodically since the internal time is not to accurate, but you can count on having no more then a few seconds of adjustment per hour. It usually happens when it reconnects to a network and makes a NTP call (that is how is detects when you have changed time-zone after a flight for ex.)

Your broadcast receiver will detect this changes also, but since leap seconds are added infrequent and are obviously a small quantity you can have logic to filter this changes from user made changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own server time instead of using client system time

Answer (score 0):

If the user is able to change the system time they will be able to get around your timer regardless. To get around a system shutdown just store the start time using System.currentTimeMillis in a file which gives you time since epoch and subtract that value from whatever the current time is.